# Add Custom Template To ListView - GridView WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, gridview, celltemplate

I currently have this XAML Code:

```xml
<ListView x:Name="listFeedSearch" Margin="-548.856,95.333,0,7.667" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="542.5" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" ItemsSource="{Binding SearchCollection}">
    <ListView.RenderTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <ScaleTransform/>
            <SkewTransform/>
            <RotateTransform/>
            <TranslateTransform/>
        </TransformGroup>
    </ListView.RenderTransform>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Width="150" Header="Feed Name" x:Name="listFeedSearchName" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FeedName}"  />
            <GridViewColumn Width="280" Header="Feed Address" x:Name="listFeedSearchAddress" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FeedUrl}" />
            <GridViewColumn Width="100" Header=" " x:Name="listFeedSearchSelect" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

What I want to do is have `listFeedSearchSelect` have a Button in the cell for every record.

What I had tried to do is, but didn't work, all it did was display as empty cell:

```xml
<GridViewColumn Header=" " Width="100" x:Name="listFeedSearchSelect">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
                <Button Content="Select" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

Can anyone help me out here, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting up your template as a resource. Like so:

```xml
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="SelectButtonColumnDataTemplate">
        <Button Content="Select" Command="{Binding SelectItemCommand}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

```xml
<ListView x:Name="listFeedSearch" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="542.5" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" ItemsSource="{Binding SearchCollection}">
    <ListView.RenderTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <ScaleTransform/>
            <SkewTransform/>                
            <RotateTransform/>                
            <TranslateTransform/>            
            </TransformGroup>        
            </ListView.RenderTransform>        
    <ListView.View>            
        <GridView>                
            <GridViewColumn Width="150" Header="Feed Name" x:Name="listFeedSearchName" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FeedName}"  />                
            <GridViewColumn Width="280" Header="Feed Address" x:Name="listFeedSearchAddress" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FeedUrl}" />                
            <GridViewColumn Width="100" Header=" " CellTemplate="{StaticResource SelectButtonColumnDataTemplate}" />            
        </GridView>        
        </ListView.View>    
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

If i just copy and paste that `GridViewColumn` of yours and *the collection has items* it does indeed display a Button as expected. The problem may be your context.